# DNS issues windows 2008 R2

Tags: dns

something is happening in my network and really till now i cant seem to find the solution, first i have 2 ISPs lets say A and B and i have DC ( DHCP And DNS) i put the dns of both the ISPS in the forwarders on the server 2008 R2
so the thing is everything is working fine except some sites will not open when i use ISP B ( when i use google dns all sites work normally again) at the same  time if i take the line of ISP B and put it on a laptop directly all websites will open using its own dns and not google can someone help plzz?
keep in mind you can see any website using ISP A with no problem at all using its dns or google dns

Comment: This, at the very least, seems to require a more detailed description of your setup in order to be answerable. As it stands, it's really little more than "I have a dual-homed setup (using an unspecified method), when one of the links go down some things stop working but they work fine when the link that went down is up". That really isn't very answerable. Also, please use proper English (this is a professionally oriented site) as well as paragraphs. Click [edit] to fix the content issues, and see the edit form's sidebar for help on formatting your post. May I also suggest taking the [tour]?

Comment: you may have better luck at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Determine DNS without filters and put them first in forwarders. Domain Name Speed Benchmark help you. https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: @user2652374 Please read [be nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice), in particular "Rudeness and belittling language are not okay. Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you."

Answer (score 1):

**Some ISPs do not allow you to use their DNS servers unless your request is coming from an IP address within their network.**  You haven't described your multihoming setup, but unless you have **explicitly configured source routing** on some device within your network so that requests to the ISP B name servers only come from your ISP B link, then you may have problems if ISP B happens to implement this kind of filtering.  This would happen if your request to the ISP B nameserver came from the external address associated with your ISP A outgoing interface.

Unless you have a strong reason to use your ISPs DNS servers it might be far easier to just use Google DNS, or some other open public DNS service.  Or you could set your internal DNS servers to just resolve from the root directly, and not configure any forwarders.

Comment: Nailed it.  This answer is correct    :)

Comment: @Zoredache thank you so much for your reply, look what i did now,    1- removed all DNS in forwarders and just kept Google DNS                                                                                                        2- ISP A still working fine on all sites ISP B just like before working fine but not all sites for example nasba.org wont open on it . any  help would be appreciated , Thank you

Comment: @Zoredache even when i deleted all forwarders and stayed on root hints some sites will not open on ISP A all sites open